# C++14 Class Function Error: "Object has no attribute 'value'"

Tags: c++, c++14

**EDIT:** Total Overhaul

I am making a programming language (similar to Python), and at least for now, I am trying to compile it to `C++`. I'm having an error where `C++` is saying that there is no member `"value"` in the class `"Object"`. This is a compilation error. I understand *why* `C++` is doing this, as it has to know the type of `value` at compile-time, and so I am asking for *alternatives*.

The only things it will be given are instances subclasses of Object, in which the member `"value"` will be defined, this is a compile error.

I can't declare the member `"value"` inside the `Object` class, because its type depends on which subclass it's in. This also has to work with floats and strings, so defining the function with an Integer instance instead of an Object instance won't work.

Here is some code with an example of how these objects will be used:

```cpp
auto user_i = std::make_unique<Integer>(2);
  std::cout << (*user_i).equals(*std::make_unique<Float>(2.0).get()) << std::endl;
```

Here are the important class definitions:

```cpp
  class Object {
  public:
    bool equals(Object& other) {
      throw "Not implemented!";
    }
  };
  class Integer: public Object {
  public:
    int value;
    Integer(int val) {
      value = val;
    }
    bool equals(Object& other) {
      return value == other.value;
    }
  };
class Float: public Object {
  public:
    double value;
    Float(double val) {
      value = val;
    }
    bool equals(Object& other) {
      return value == other.value;
    }
  };
class String: public Object {
  public:
    string value;
    String(string val) {
      value = val;
    }
    bool equals(Object& other) {
      return value.compare(other.value) == 0;
    }
  };
```

It should not be the case that `2 == "2"`, but it should be the case that `2 == 2.0 == 2.000` etc.

There is then the added complication of methods like `add` (by this I mean returning a value, still not modifying the object). The `equals` method suggested by @Michael Karcher would work fine, but for example `2+3` should return `5`, not `5.00000`.

For even more trouble, User-Defined `Object`s (`Class`s in my language) should be able to override methods like `add`.

Comment: Just a heads-up: "attribute" has a _very_ specific meaning in C++ and it does _not_ mean member, which I believe is what you're interested in. In your code example, `value` is a _member_. Attributes on the other hand `[[look_like_this]]`

Comment: This may fly in various scripting languages, but won't work in c++ since the *type* of `value` isn't known

Answer (score 4):

Your example has a couple of issues besides you main issues. I start with the minor issues to get them out of the way.

1. You need declare `equals` as `virtual` in the base class. *Opposed to Java*, dynamic dispatch is *not* the default in C++, but must be requested per method using the `virtual` attribute like this:

```
class Object {
public:
  virtual bool equals(Object other) {
    throw "Not implemented";
  }
}
```

2. You are passing the object you compare to **by value**. *Opposed to Java*, in C++ even class types can be passed by value. This means that the function `equals` gets a copy of an `Object` to compare to - and *just* that. The parts of the object you want to compare to, including the `value` member, do not get copied into the argument passed to `equals`. You should pass the parameter **by reference**. As your `equals` function does not need to modify the object you compare to, a reference without write permission (commonly called a *const reference* due to the syntax) is enough:

```
class Object {
public:
  virtual bool equals(const Object& other) {
    throw "Not implemented";
  }
}
```

3. If you are writing a base class that just provides a function signature which needs to be overridden in every derived class, you don't make it throw something, but you instead make it abstract by declaring it as a *pure virtual* function, using the `=0` syntax. This prevents you from accidentally creating `Object` instances that can not be compared. This would have caught the missing pass-by-reference:

```
class Object {
public:
  virtual bool equals(const Object& other) = 0;
}
```

Now, let's address your question:

This approach works in dynamically typed languages like JavaScript or Python, but it does not work in C++. **During compilation**, the compiler has to know where it finds the member `value` in the object `other` and its type. If you just pass in any `Object`, the compiler has no way of knowing it. And even *you* don't know: The type might be `int` or `float`. So neither you nor the compiler know whether there is a float value or an int value in the object you pass for comparison. If `Integer` objects should be comparable to both `Integer` and `Float` objects, you either need to comparison methods or you need a way to get a generic `value` of a common type. In this case, on machines with 32-Bit integers, *every integer value is exactly representable in a `double` variable*. You could add a second function to the `Object` class called `as_double` like this:

```
class Object {
public:
  virtual bool equals(const Object &other) const = 0;
  virtual double as_double() const = 0;
}
```

I also marked the methods `const`, which means you may call them on objects or using references you may not write to. Now you can implement `Integer` and `Float` like this:

```
class Integer: public Object {
public:
  int value;
  Integer(int val) {
    value = val;
  }
  bool equals(const Object & other) const {
    return value == other.as_double();
  }
  double as_double() const {
    return value;
  }
};
class Float: public Object {
public:
  double value;
  Float(double val) {
    value = val;
  }
  bool equals(const Object & other) const {
    return value == other.as_double();
  }
  double as_double() const {
    return value;
  }
};
```

And, if you look at the `equals` method, its now nearly the same for both types: You extract the value of argument as double, and compare it to the local value (in the case of `Integer`, the local value gets implicitly converted to double, too. So you could also use a generic comparison implementation that calls `to_double` on both objects, and you don't have to bother implementing `equals` in each subclass:

```
class Object {
public:
  bool equals(const Object& other) const {
    return as_double() == other.as_double();
  }
  virtual double as_double() const = 0;
}
```

Note, this only works because `double` actually is able to represent all values - even those stored in `Integers`. If your actual use-case does not have such a common type you can convert to, you need a more complicated solution.

Comment: consolidating all the possible `value`s into a `double` certainly does address the immediate problem, but given the pattern shown in the question, I would infer the need for a `String` object type as well, which wouldn't mesh well with a simple `double`. other ways would include using `std::variant` with all possible `value` types with a single custom comparison function that would implement the type mixmatch issues. but thats just a hunch :p

Comment: As soon as you add strings, you open a new can of worms. Is the Integer 3 the equal to the string `"03"`? Is it equal to the string `"3"`. If the answer to both is "yes", should `equals` be transitive? In that case `"03"` and `"3"` need to be considered equal, too. This is not to devaluate your comment, but just to point out the problems *everyone* gets when implementing cross-type equality. The `std::variant`-approach for comparison is indeed one of the most idiomatic C++ ways to implement a cross-type comparison strategy.

Comment: First of All @MichaelKarcher, thanks so much for your detailed response. I am quite new to c++ so all these helpful tips are very, well, helpful! However, I do want to include strings, as kmdreko said, and there are some additional complications besides this. I have edited the question with some revised information.

Comment: Also @MichaelKarcher is there any advantage to using `const` when no `Object`s will be read-only?

Comment: In C++, it is considered good style to only request modification rights when you actually need them. This is called "const correctness". The advantage of const-correct code is that even if no object is read-only, you can still use references without write permissions, like in `void DisplayObject(const Object &value)`. A method signature like this clearly points out that DisplayObject is not going to modify the value. But then, inside DisplayObject, the object is treated as-if it were read-only to enforce it.

Comment: Ok, thanks @MichaelKarcher. Would you mind suggesting a new response based on my edits?

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

- C++ is not a dynamically typed language, but a statically typed language. A variable's type is determined at compile time, and not runtime.
- To have dynamic nature with the type, you need to have a **polymorphic** class - i.e. class having virtual functions. Through one or more virtual functions, you achieve the dynamic nature of the (class) type. The derived type (class) would (re)implement the necessary virtual functions

If you want to have types that seem dynamic but are static at compile time; then you can use templates. For example, an `Add` function can be:

```
template<typename Type>
Type Add(Type a, Type b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

And call them with any type:

```
Add(1,2); // int
Add(4.5, 5.0); // double
```

In the function, if you want to know the type, you can use certain helper functions like `is_same`:

```
Type Add(Type a, Type b)
{
   if(std::is_same<Type, int>::value) 
   {
       // Do whatever when 'int' is passed
   }
  ...
}
```

The same approach can be used in **class templates** also. You may have (partial) template class specialization. `vector` with type `bool` is one example.

`std::distance` and `std::advance` are another examples which rely on the type of the container (in a simlpe sense) and are implemented differently (random access or sequence access).

Comment: But then `2+2.1` would not be legal without additional complications.

Comment: I kept things simple. We cannot elaborate on each and everything on a simple answer. See my article on all this: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/257589/an-idiots-guide-to-cplusplus-templates-part-1

Answer (score 0):

The equal functions uses Object as the parameters type. Calling `other.value` does not work as you already pointed out Object does not have a parameter value. From the compiler point of view it will never get anything with a parameter value.

I suggest you rewrite the function definitions of `equals` to `bool equals(Integer& other)` and `bool equals(Float& other)`.

Comment: But you should be able to do `2 > 3.1`

Comment: @LlamaBoy In that you could consider using a template for the function equals and its type of parameter. `template<TYPE> bool equals(const TYPE& other)`. This will only work for data types that actually have the equality operators defined for them. Thus not for strings.